# How to reuse http request result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to make requests for my codes.

I have something like

```
if(hasProduct) {
    product.getProduct(, function(product) {
        $scope.name = product.name;
        $scope.price = product.price;
        $scope.region = product.region;
        //do other things.
    })
} else {
     product.getProduct(, function(product) {
         $scope.name = product.name;   // I need to get product name whether hasProduct is true or false
    })
    //do something
}
```

my question is if `hasProduct` is false, I still need to make a request to get the product name but I don't feel like making two identical requests in different condition is practical. I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just as a matter of style, it's usually better to just store the resource (body of the http request) in the scope instead of storing each little bit of it. Then use `$watch` to respond to changes in its fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make one request and use the variable in the callback to branch your logic.

```
product.getProduct(, function(product) {
    if (hasProduct) //do stuff
    else //do other stuff
});
```

If the hasProduct variable changes (like if it's in a loop) you can wrap the callback function like so, this way the hasProduct variable is bound:

```
product.getProduct(, (function(hasProduct) { return function(product) {
    if (hasProduct) //do stuff
    else //do other stuff
})(hasProduct));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code to use the `hasProduct` value after the request completes. But if you do that:

Please, use an IIFE closure:

```
(function (hasProduct) {
    product.getProduct(, function(product) {
        //Executed asynchronously after request completes
        $scope.name = product.name;
        if (hasProduct) {
             $scope.price = product.price;
             $scope.region = product.region;
            //do other things.
        };
    });
})(hasProduct);
```

By using an IIFE closure, the value of `hasProduct` is preserved and available when the request's promise resolves. This avoids bugs caused by `hasProduct` changing between the initiation of the request and the completion of the request.

For more information [Immediately-invoked function expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)